# Merging Collection if values are equals for a specific key with Laravel

Tags: laravel, collections

I have 2 different collections which look like this

Collection 1  :

```
{typesession_id: 3, formation_id: 7, codeformation: "FR8", id: 3, nomformation: "Sécurité électrique", …}
{typesession_id: 3, formation_id: 8, codeformation: "FR8", id: 4, nomformation: "Sécurité incendie", …}
```

Collection 2 :

```
{datesession: "2018-03-15", debutsession: "08:30:00", finsession: "12:00:00", typesession_id: 1, title: "Gestes d'urgence - Soignant", …}
{datesession: "2018-03-16", debutsession: "08:30:00", finsession: "12:00:00", typesession_id: 3, title: "eLearning", …}
{datesession: "2018-03-17", debutsession: "08:30:00", finsession: "12:00:00", typesession_id: 3, title: "eLearning", …}
```

Those 2 collection have a common key ...
I'm trying to recover the elements of the Collection 2 which have the same value for the "typesession_id" key ... 
For example if my collection 1 have elements with typesession_id equal to 1 and 2, i want to have items of the collection 2 with values 1 and 2.

My newCollection should be :

```
{typesession_id: 3, formation_id: 7, codeformation: "FR8", id: 3, nomformation: "Sécurité électrique", datesession: "2018-03-16", debutsession: "08:30:00", finsession: "12:00:00", title: "eLearning", …}
{typesession_id: 3, formation_id: 7, codeformation: "FR8", id: 4, nomformation: "Sécurité électrique", datesession: "2018-03-17", debutsession: "08:30:00", finsession: "12:00:00", title: "eLearning", …}


{typesession_id: 3, formation_id: 8, codeformation: "FR8", id: 3, nomformation: "Sécurité incendie",  datesession: "2018-03-16", debutsession: "08:30:00", finsession: "12:00:00", title: "eLearning", …}
{typesession_id: 3, formation_id: 8, codeformation: "FR8", id: 4, nomformation: "Sécurité incendie",  datesession: "2018-03-17", debutsession: "08:30:00", finsession: "12:00:00", title: "eLearning", …}
```

In other terms : my first collection allows me to know which are the trainings an user can do ... and my second collection allows me to have information concerning sessions available for a specific type of session (typesession_id). I want to have a full list of combination based on typesession_id ...

I tried to figure it out by myself on Laravel guide but i didn't really find my solution...

Comment: could you provide the resutl you're trying to achieve?

Comment: i changed my question and i hope it's more clear now ... i would need combination based on a key / value ...

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested but code likes below would probably work:

```
$collection1 = $collection1->groupBy('typessesion_id');

$result = $collection2->map(function($item, $key) {
    $typesession_id = $item->typesession_id;
    $item_clone = $item;
    $data = $collection1[$typesession_id]->map(function($it, $k) use ($item_clone) {
        if ($typesession_id == $it->typesession_id) {
            return $item_clone->merge($it);
        }

        return $it;
    });

    return $data->merge($item);
});

dd($result);
```

Comment: So you're giving unverified answer?

Comment: Yes, it's based on my current task with laravel. You can see lots of non-tested answers in SO and they work.